# laravel query returns weird order

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

So I came across a **bug** in my '**bugoverview**' page. (how ironic)..
this weird way of order came to my knowledge after an bug was deleted out of the database (`id : 7` was deleted)

Anyways the problem is as seen in the picture :

[image]

I get all the rows in a simple blade foreach.

my query codes are :

```
$bugs_all = Bug::with('klant','user')->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
```

and

```
$projects_all = Project::all();
```

my foreach code :

```
@foreach($projects_all as $project)
    @foreach($bugs_all as $bug)
        @if(count($bugs_all) > 0)
            @if($bug->project_id == $project->id)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$bug->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{substr($bug->titel,0,15)}}...</td>
                    <td>{{$bug->status}}</td>
                    <td>{{$bug->soort}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($bug->prioriteit == 'laag')
                            <span class="label label-success">Laag</span>
                        @elseif($bug->prioriteit == 'gemiddeld')
                            <span class="label label-warning">Gemmideld</span>
                        @elseif($bug->prioriteit == 'hoog')
                            <span class="label label-danger">Hoog</span>
                        @elseif($bug->prioriteit == 'kritisch')
                            <span class="label label-purple">Kritisch</span>
                        @else
                            <span class="label label-info">Geen prioriteit</span>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>{{date('d-m-y - H:i',strtotime($bug->eind_datum))}}</td>
                    @if($bug->klant)
                        <td>{{$bug->klant->voornaam .' '.$bug->klant->tussenvoegsel.' '. $bug->klant->achternaam}}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{$project->projectnaam}}</td>
                    @if($bug->user)
                        <td>{{$bug->user->voornaam .' '.$bug->user->tussenvoegsel.' '. $bug->user->achternaam}}</td>
                    @else
                        <td>Geen</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>
                        <a href="/bugchat/{{$bug->id}}" class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endif

        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is it a single project bug nummer you have posted...?

Comment: no those are 5 rows which are ordered via mysql.. @BasheerAhmed

Comment: dd($bugs_all->toArray()) in a controller and see the order?

Comment: Then the order is 9,8,6,5,4 as it has to be.. only it won't show that way.. @BasheerAhmed

Comment: Why it has to be 9,8,6...? But rather it should be in ascending order 4,5,6,8,9...

Comment: oh yeah sorry i tried desc for a sec haha anyways both work when dd() but now when showing them in the view. @BasheerAhmed

Comment: Then it means your projects are not in ascending order

Comment: Post your code of getting all projects...

Comment: dude they are now still same problem. when i dd($bugs_all)toArray()) they show up in the right order asc or desc don't matter. it's the problem that the row with id 5 always gets at the bottom.

Comment: i already did refresh the page please. @BasheerAhmed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98135/discussion-between-stefano-groenland-and-basheer-ahmed).

Comment: If your table is InnoDB - InnoDB is an engine that re-uses space.  You create records 1, 2 and 3.  Then you delete record 2 and create record 4, the default order is Id ASC as follows:  1, 4, 3 - because record 4 replaced the space of record 2.  I would say this occurs because you're not ordering relationships correctly, with Eloquent you can also use `orderBy` on relations too.

Comment: someone helped me out already waiting for the answer post. thanks everybody for posting.

Comment: @StefanoGroenland Okay, no worries.  I have elaborated my comment in an answer for future reference.  Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question contains some ambiguity, without seeing an ERD or your table/relationship structure it's hard to truely help.

However, I assume you are using InnoDB and you are not ordering your relationships correctly.

First of all InnoDB is an engine that will re-uses deleted space. For example:  You create records 1, 2 and 3. Then you delete record 2 and create record 4.  The default order is *auto_increment* in ascending order (this is not explicitly order by `id` ASC).

With that said the order of your bugs are as follows: 1, 4, 3 - this is simply because record 4 replaced the space of record 2 (which was previously deleted).

Secondly I would simply advise you set-up your relationships correctly.  I assume your Projects are related to Bugs somehow? Something along the following lines would suffice:

```
// Inside your Project model.
public function bugs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Bug', 'bug_id', 'id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
}

// Inside your Bug model.
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'bug_id', 'id');
}
```

To get all bugs for all projects:

```
$projects = Project::with('bug.klant', 'bug.user')->all();
```

Inside your blade template, you can do:

```
@foreach ($project->bugs as $bug)

    {{ $bug->user }}
    {{ $bug->klant }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: had it somewhat different but i got it working thanks,

Comment: the problem was not about Database engines and auto increment at all ;) Just the outer loop through the projects caused the problem. but anyway. good answer ;)

Comment: @shock_gone_wild sure, not the problem in this case, but the information about InnoDB engine may be helpful to someone with a similar problem.

Comment: yeah it definitely is ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case ist, that you have an outer loop that walks through the different projects. As each bug is associated with a different project, your check for the project id 'destroys' the ordering of the bugs. In your code the bugs are ordered per project....

But you don't even need that outer loop. If you define a **belongsTo** relationship in you bugs model you could simply access the bugs like:

```
@foreach($bugs_all as $bug) 
   $bug->project->projectnaam;
   .... 
@endforeach
```

So you have all information about the bug's project and keep your defined order.