# Laravel Eloquent - Sorting by a column on a joined table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This example from the Laravel documentation will order the posts by created_at within the users.

```
$users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

}])->get();
```

How would I turn that around so Users are ordered by the created_at date on the posts? I.e. I want to order Users by those with the most recent post.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered something similar [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315840/laravel-query-returns-weird-order/34317134?noredirect=1).  You can simply do `orderBy` after any relationship definition.

```
public function relation()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Related', 'foreign_key', 'local_id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
}
```

Comment: Is this not only ordering the related items by id? In my example I want to order the Users by their related posts created_at date. Your example doesn't change the order that the Users are returned in does it?

Comment: You're right, the field is irrelevent but it only sorts the relation data. i'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like either answer actually answers the question.

You can order the child models using Eloquent relationships, but you can't order the parent models using the attributes of the child models with Eloquent relationships. You need to use [joins](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins) for this.

For example:

```
$users = App\User::selectRaw('users.*, MAX(posts.created_at) as latest_post_timestamp')
    ->join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->orderBy('latest_post_timestamp', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

Join the posts and users table. Select all user attributes + the max created_at attribute of the post, which I aliased as "latest_post_timestamp". I use this alias to order the results.

This will not eager load the posts so if you still need to do that, then just add the [with](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method like this:

```
$users = App\User::with('posts')
    ->selectRaw('users.*, MAX(posts.created_at) as latest_post_timestamp')
    ->join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->orderBy('latest_post_timestamp', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```